# change this script to make split a txt file in Unix chunks?

Tags: batch

I have this script and can split huge txt files in small chunks in Windows/DOS format

How can I make some changes to split in Unix format?

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "nLines=2000"
    set "line=0"
    for /f %%a in ('type total.txt^|find /c /v ""') do set "fileLines=%%a"

    < "total.txt" (for /l %%a in (1 1 %fileLines%) do (
        set /p "data="
        set /a "file=1+line/%nLines%", "line+=1"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        >>"pass!file!.txt" echo(!data!
        endlocal
    ))

    endlocal
```

Comment: [Windows command to convert Unix line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17579553)

Comment: yes yes yes  /r/n to /n or something like that ,can u do that?

Comment: Read the link. It answers your question....

Comment: are many options there ,1 want to'' split and convert'' at the same time not convert after spliting is done,tell me wich line i must change in that script above, thanks